# Modificar script

Tags: powershell

He de configurar una impresora en red y lo que he de hacer es modificar un script en Windows 7 que ya esta hecho en internet. Lo que no sé es como cambiar la ruta de la impresora o que hay que hacer  para que cuando se ejecute en los demás equipos  se añada automáticamente la impresora al equipo que sea y se pueda imprimir mediante ese script asi no hay que buscar la impresora por la red y conectarla cada vez.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

En la ultima linea del script, donde dice ***"\\server\impresora"*** debes sustituir ***server*** por el nombre de tu servidor e ***impresora*** por la impresora que tienes instalada en el servidor y quieres utilizar en los otros equipos.